# Special Letters not working on KATEX on Github

Tags: github, markdown, katex

After May 2022, github are now accepting KATEX directly on markdown using `$$$$`

I'm trying to use the following letters on markdown using the `$$$$` special characters to use the KATEX on my github but the following letters are not working.

| Code | Letter displayed | expected |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `$$\N$$` | $$\N$$ | [image] |
| `$$\Z$$` | $$\Z$$ | [image] |
| `$$\Reals$$` | $$\Reals$$ | [image] |
| `$$\R$$` | $$\R$$ | [image] |
| `$$\natnums$$` | $$\natnums$$ | [image] |

in github:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some study, I find out a KATEX command called `\mathbb{text}` who cna change the font from the text inside the curly brackets

One example:

```latex
$$ A =  \lbrace x \in \mathbb{N} \space | \space x < 5 \rbrace $$
```

Some information:

`\lbrace and \rbrace` are the `{ }` curly brace symbol in KATEX

`\space` insert space between texts

In github thanks to `\mathbb{text}` it can make the symbol i showed in my question:

[image]

The table of symbol and code

| Code | Symbol |
| --- | --- |
| `$$\mathbb{N}$$` | $$\mathbb{N}$$ |
| `$$\mathbb{Z}$$` | $$\mathbb{Z}$$ |
| `$$\mathbb{R}$$` | $$\mathbb{R}$$ |

On Github preview:

[image: github preview markdown]